# org-babel and remote sql commands

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, sql

I'm using org-babel to do litterate programming and I find it very convenient. I am able to execute shell commands on remote hosts, and local database commands with the postgres client. To open a file as postgres user, it would look for example like

```
C-x C-f /sshx:user@remotehost|sudo:postgres@remotehost:/tmp/testfile
```

To do so on Emacs 24.5.1, I needed to add:

```
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
             '(nil "\\`postgres\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
             '((regexp-quote (system-name)) nil nil))
```

So far, I have failed to understand how one could execute a postgresql (or mysql if you so choose) command on a remote server. The database **server is not accessible directly** over the network, I have to ssh into the remote host, su as the postgres user and then I'm able to execute commands through the psql client.

How could one use such a command:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine postgresql :ExtraParametersIfNeeded
SELECT * from pg_database
#+END_SRC
```

On a remote host? I know the :dir switch, but have so far only been able to use it for shell scripts.

Many thanks!

Comment: You could do some SSH tunnelling... You would do something akin to "`ssh yourbox -L7590:127.0.0.1:7590`" replacing the "`7590`" with whatever port your database is on. Then, in your Org babel block, you can use the "`:cmdline`" header argument to set a command line argument to set the database port. The whole thing might look something like this at the top of your Org file: "`#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql :engine mysql :dbhost 127.0.0.1 :dbuser someone :dbpassword somepassword :database database :cmdline -P7590
`". After `C-c C-c`-ing that, you can use any SQL block in your buffer like that.

Comment: Hi, I thought about it and I could not find any other way myself too. If you make it an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Well... I posted that as a comment because, while it solves your problem, it doesn't really answer your question. Nothing has changed on the Emacs end; you would just be creating an SSH tunnel manually so that the database *can* be accessed directly as opposed to making Emacs control the entire process through a header argument or some arbitrary configuration--so, I don't think I'll make an answer of that. Maybe someone else knows of a way to tell Org-babel to create this tunnel without any manual fudging.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it is working now because of updates in *Emacs* and *tramp*, but as there is no accepted solution and no exact snippet of code for those who are looking for answer, I'm providing one which is working in *Emacs 25* and recent *org-mode* and *tramp*.

As you already proposed in your question, `:dir` is the solution, just take your *src* section and add same string as you used for opening files to the `:dir` arugment. There is no need to do SSH tunnel as this is something *tramp* can do out of the box.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine postgresql :dir /sshx:user@remotehost|sudo:postgres@remotehost:
SELECT * FROM pg_database
#+END_SRC
```

Working just find and returns:

```
#+RESULTS:
| datname             | datdba | encoding | datcollate  | datctype    | datistemplate | datallowconn | datconnlimit | datlastsysoid | datfrozenxid | datminmxid | dattablespace | datacl                              |
|---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------|
| postgres            |     10 |        6 | C.UTF-8     | C.UTF-8     | f             | t            |           -1 |         12408 |          545 |          1 |          1663 |                                     |
| template0           |     10 |        6 | C.UTF-8     | C.UTF-8     | t             | f            |           -1 |         12408 |          545 |          1 |          1663 | {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres} |
```

Comment: Confirming that this also works for emacs 26(.1), org 9.1.9, tramp 2.3.3.26.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an org user, so I can answer only from the Tramp point of view. The Tramp settings you have shown above are not needed (`add-to-list` forms), since you are using ad-hoc multi-hops in your file name. So I assume a simple `:dir "/sshx:user@remotehost|sudo:postgres@remotehost:/path/to/dir"` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. In order to execute shell scripts (using the :dir command) I had to use the lines mentionned above, as I was getting a message in the style of "sudo is only allowed on local host".

Comment: You're right, there is a subtle error in Tramp. I could reproduce the problem with the following code snippet:  
  
`#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /ssh:remotehost|sudo:postgres@remotehost:/tmp`  `whoami`    
`#+END_SRC`    
  
As workaround, you could do something like this (untested):  
  
`#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp`  
`(progn`  
`(require 'tramp)`  
`(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist  '(nil "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:")))`  
`#+END_SRC`  
  
`#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo:remotehost:/tmp`  
`whoami`  
`#+END_SRC`